# Does SSL also encrypt AJAX posts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

I am posting to SSL server with jQuery.  Will my any AJAX posts be protected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just like normal https pages

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are accessing HTTPS server, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Javascript obeys the same origin security policy. If the html is served via SSL than the communication through JS must be through SSL as well. See the Wikipedia article: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)